# Using forEach instead of map , trying to access objects in an Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to build a React Recipe App. I am making API request for Recipe Search.
My question is about using map in this line

```
 {recipes.map((recipe) => (
        <Recipe />
      ))}
```

We are trying to access the objects inside of the array. Right? Yes, this works. However, I don't get why

```
 {recipes.forEach ((recipe) => (
        <Recipe />
      ))}
```

doesn't work. Could you please explain? The whole code is below.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Recipe from "./Recipe";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
  const APP_KEY = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, []);

  //yeni bir fonksiyon yazıyorum. take care of fetching all data
  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data.hits);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form className="search-form">
        <input className="search-bar" type="text" />
        <button className="search-button" type="submit">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
      {recipes.map((recipe) => (
        <Recipe />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Recipe.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Recipe = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Calories</p>
      <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Recipe;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.map()` returns the **ARRAY** of the `<Recipe />` entities, and `.forEach()` doesn't return ANYTHING.  React does not render by side-effect - it needs the JSX returned.

Comment: Oh.. I see.  Thank you ! So map renders like this?  [Recipe , Recipe , Recipe , Recipe ] 
I couldn't image an array with its elements Components. How can I see that array ?

Comment: You can assign the entire map to a variable outside and then console log it.

const recipesList = recipes.map((recipe) => (
        <Recipe />
      )); 
console.log(recipesList);

Then inside return you can simply use this variable to render.
{recipesList}

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` version doesn’t return an array of rendered elements like the `map` version does. The elements rendered inside the forEach don’t exist outside the scope of the forEach function, whereas the map version returns the elements in an array.